# Actionscript 3 Video loop

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to have embed video in flash game and have it looped. Is there a way to do it? As my code or more likely .seek or .resume dont give any effect? Am I using wrong commands or?

```
[Embed(source = "fast.flv", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
public var bytes:Class;
public var vidNS:NetStream 
public var video:Video = new Video(1280, 720);
public var ns:NetStream;    


public function Main() {
Doit();
}

    private function Doit():void{

    addChild(video);

        var vidNC:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); vidNC.connect(null);
        vidNS = new NetStream(vidNC);

        var metaListener :Object = new Object(); metaListener = { onMetaData: process_Metadata };
        vidNS.client = metaListener;
        vidNS.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, videoStatusHandler);      

        vidNS.play(null);

    var file:ByteArray = new bytes();
    vidNS.appendBytes(file);
    video.attachNetStream(vidNS);

}   
        function process_Metadata (in_Data :Object):void
        {
            trace("duration is : " + in_Data.duration );
        }

    function videoStatusHandler (event:NetStatusEvent):void 
    {
        if (event.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty") 
        {
            trace('loop')
            vidNS.seek(0); vidNS.resume();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `NetStream.Buffer.Empty` you should be listening to (does that `loop` trace come trough) ? I thought it would be something like listeneing to the [NetDataEvent for `onPlayStatus ( for "NetStream.Play.Complete")`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onPlayStatus)

Comment: umm, yes trace comment "loop" is coming out, its just like vidNS.seek(0); vidNS.resume(); didn't give me any effect, or  maybe I wrong attached embed video to NetStream and thats why nothing happen. Video is played, when completed trace comment "loop" is comming out, but nothing else happen.

Comment: what about calling `play()` again instead of `resume()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop by just simply re-feeding the bytes to the decoder (NetStream)

It's possible that you also need to involve the option [RESET_BEGIN](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStreamAppendBytesAction.html):

```
yourNS.appendBytesAction( NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN );
```

Try setting your code like below:

```
[Embed(source = "fast.flv", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
public var bytes:Class;

public var vidNS:NetStream;
public var video:Video = new Video(1280, 720);
public var ns:NetStream;

//# declare these vars outside of a function for global access
public var file:ByteArray = new bytes(); 
public var vidNC:NetConnection;
public var metaListener :Object;

public function Main() 
{
    Doit();
}

private function Doit():void
{
    addChild(video);

    vidNC = new NetConnection(); vidNC.connect(null);
    vidNS = new NetStream(vidNC);

    metaListener new Object(); metaListener = { onMetaData: process_Metadata };
    vidNS.client = metaListener;
    vidNS.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, videoStatusHandler);      

    vidNS.play(null);

    //var file:ByteArray = new bytes();
    vidNS.appendBytes(file); //# feed video bytes to decoder
    video.attachNetStream(vidNS);

}   

function process_Metadata (in_Data :Object):void
{
    trace("duration is : " + in_Data.duration );
}

function videoStatusHandler (event:NetStatusEvent):void 
{
    if (event.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty") 
    {
        trace('now doing: looping...')

        //# there is no timeline ".seek" in appendBytes mode, use ".seek" to clear the buffer for a new re-feed

        vidNS.seek(0); //clears the current buffer (video data is removed)
        vidNS.appendBytesAction( NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN ); //re-set timestamps for decoder
        vidNS.appendBytes(file); //re-feed video bytes to decoder

    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yup, yourNS.appendBytesAction( NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN ); was the thing that I was been mising, thank you. Seems like   if (event.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty")  Is no longer working afterr first loop, so a a little changed code to make it work. Not sure if thats is the right way ^^, but i just deleted whole "videoStatusHandler " function and put those 2 last lines (appendBytesAction + appendBytes) into process_Metadata and its working like it should :)

Answer (score 1):

So Thanks to VC. One i ended up with this code:

```
[Embed(source="1.flv", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
public var bytes:Class;
public var vidNS:NetStream;
public var video:Video = new Video(1280, 720);
public var file:ByteArray = new bytes(); 
public var vidNC:NetConnection;
public var metaListener :Object;

public function Main() 
{
    Doit();
}

private function Doit():void
{
    addChild(video);

    vidNC = new NetConnection(); vidNC.connect(null);
    vidNS = new NetStream(vidNC);

    metaListener new Object(); metaListener = { onMetaData: process_Metadata };
    vidNS.client = metaListener;   

    vidNS.play(null);    
    vidNS.appendBytes(file); 
    video.attachNetStream(vidNS);    
} 

function process_Metadata (in_Data :Object):void
{
    trace("loop ");
            vidNS.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);
            vidNS.appendBytes(file);
}
```

Its working like it should, but i'm not sure if thats the right way of doing it ^^.

Comment: `...Working like it should, but I'm not sure if that's the right way of doing it` Welcome to software **engineering**. You just be happy it works as expected no matter the path. PS: I think your two `appendBytes` lines work because when the FLV gets re-added it automatically also triggers the `process_Metadata` function. To me, those lines are in the right place. Else If needed, you could just put those lines in some `function re_loop()  : void`. +1 for sharing.